# I/O with fread and fwrite

Tags: c

Below is my simple cat problem, which reads a file and print it on terminal. When I set the BUFISZE macro to 10, it works fine. If I set BUFSIZE to 100, it prints part of the file. If I set BUFIZE to 1024, it prints nothing. Could you anyone please explain what is going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv){

      char buf[BUFSIZE];
      FILE *fp;

      if( (fp = fopen(*++argv, "r")) == NULL){
          printf("cannot open %s\n", *argv);
          return 1;
       }

      while( fread(buf, BUFSIZE, 1, fp) == 1 ) 
          if (fwrite(buf,strlen(buf), 1, stdout) != 1 ){
                printf("write error.\n");
                return 2;
           }

     printf("\n");
     return 0;      
  }
```

Comment: Your file is less than 1024 bytes, so `fread` is telling you it could not read an object of that size. I would swap the `size` and `count` parameters and always read `count` bytes of `size` 1.

Comment: `strlen(buf)` won't do what you expect. Log away what it returns.

Comment: if you are simulating cat, you are possibly dealing with human-readable files. `fgets(3)` is a better choice than fread.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `strlen` here; you are not dealing with null-terminated strings here. You read fixed blocksizes. You should write the same amount of chars that you have read.

`fread` returns the number of elements of the given size that were successfully read. Use this information in your call to `fread`. For this to work, you must treat the data as `BUFSIZE` bytes, not as one block of `BUFSIZE` bytes. (If that sounds esoteric: Swap your second and third parameters in `fread` and `fwrite`. These functions cannot return a number greater than their third parameter, the element count.)

So:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
size_t n;

do {
    n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    if (n > 0) fwrite(buf, 1, n, stdout);
} while (n == BUFSIZE);
```